# Pagination For Qt's Listview

Tags: c++, qt, pagination, qml

I'm creating a generic pagination helper class.
 Personally I use this class for navigating through Records which are loaded into 
 any sequential containers e.g `QVector`, `QList` etc.

The idea is that you load your data from any source such as a database, cloud, file,  etc.

You specify how many results you want to load per page and it generates
a pagination list or page numbers which you can wire up with any model on QML 
 side.

Is this is a suitable approach, or is there a better way to do it?
 Any guides, suggestions or remarks are welcome.

This is best of my understanding; I could be completely wrong or there might be solutions out there which are more effective.

***Just to sum it up:***

**`IPaginationHandler`** is an interface class.

**`PaginationHandler`** class is an actual implementation.
   This class has an opaque pointer to actual data members.

In **PaginationHandler.cpp**

There is an **`Implementation`** class which has the data members.

**Key Members** are:

1.`QHash<int,int>` page indexes which will hold the value of which page number would have how many results. e.g for source container of 47 Size it generates values  `(1,10) (2,10) (3,10) (4,10) (5,7)`. This member is mutated in `populatePageIndex()` method.

2.`QVector<int>` which will contain actual page numbers like 1,2,3....15 etc
 this gets mutated in `populatePageNumberContainer()` method

3.`int processRecords` is like ref counter for records that has been processed 
 by navigation, which in turn sets whether you are at the start of Data source or at the end of it; it also helps on UI part for navigation controls visibility.

```
// IPaginationHandler.h
class IPaginationHandler : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    // This is for navigation Control on UI side so you can set visibility or 
    // other visual changes 
    Q_PROPERTY(bool canMoveAhead READ canMoveAhead WRITE setCanMoveAhead NOTIFY canMoveAheadChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(bool canMoveBack READ canMoveBack WRITE setCanMoveBack NOTIFY canMoveBackChanged)
public:
    explicit IPaginationHandler(QObject *parent=nullptr):QObject(parent){}
    virtual ~IPaginationHandler(){}

    enum class CursorDirection{
        MoveForward=0x001,
        MoveBackward,
        MoveLast,
        MoveFirst
    };Q_ENUM(CursorDirection)

public:
    virtual QHash<int,int> pageIndex()const=0;

    virtual void populatePageIndex(const int &sourceContainerSize,const int &resultPerPage)=0;

    virtual QVector<int> pageNumber()const=0;
    // QML was giving me error for c++ enums so I know there is way to do that 
   // but I couldn't figure it out so here we are.
    virtual void populatePageNumberContainer(const int &direction,const int &totalRecords)=0;

    virtual void setNavigationControl(const int &totalRecords,const int &sourceContainerSize,const int &direction)=0;

    virtual bool canMoveAhead()const=0;
    virtual void setCanMoveAhead(bool val)=0;

    virtual bool canMoveBack()const=0;
    virtual void setCanMoveBack(bool val)=0;


signals:
    void canMoveAheadChanged();
    void canMoveBackChanged();

    void prePageNumbersChanged();
    void postPageNumbersChanged();
};
```

Now the actual implementation:

PaginationHandler.h

```
 // PaginationHandler.h

class PaginationHandler : public IPaginationHandler
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    PaginationHandler(QObject *parent=nullptr);
    ~PaginationHandler()override;

     QHash<int, int> pageIndex() const override;
     void populatePageIndex(const int &sourceContainerSize, const int &resultPerPage) override;
     QVector<int> pageNumber() const override;
     void populatePageNumberContainer(const int &direction, const int &totalRecords) override;
     void setNavigationControl(const int &totalRecords, const int &sourceContainerSize, const int &direction) override;
     bool canMoveAhead() const override;
     void setCanMoveAhead(bool val) override;
     bool canMoveBack() const override;
     void setCanMoveBack(bool val) override;
private:
     class Implementation;
     std::unique_ptr<Implementation> opaque;

};
```

PaginationHandler.cpp

```
#include "Paginationhandler.h"
#include <QHash>
#include <QVector>
#include <cmath> 

const int TEN{10};
const int ONE{1};
const int ZERO{0};
const int FIVE{5};

PaginationHandler::PaginationHandler(QObject *parent):IPaginationHandler(parent)
{
    opaque = std::make_unique<Implementation>(this);
}

PaginationHandler::~PaginationHandler()
{

}


class PaginationHandler::Implementation{

public:
    PaginationHandler *handler{nullptr};
    QHash<int,int> pageIndexs; // I fixed this hash to 5 Pages.
    /* For example source Container with 100 size and result per page is 10
     * this hash would hold (0,10)... (4,10)
     * but it won't exceed more than 5 Pages.
    */
    QVector<int> pageNumbers; // this is the root container which will hold page 
                              // numbers

    int resultsPerPage;
    int totalPages;
    int currentPage;

    bool canMoveAhead{false};
    bool canMoveBack{false};

    int processedRecords;

public:
    Implementation(PaginationHandler *mInstance);
};

PaginationHandler::Implementation::Implementation(PaginationHandler *mInstance):handler(mInstance)
{
    resultsPerPage = TEN;
    totalPages = FIVE;
    currentPage = ONE;
    processedRecords = ZERO;
}


QHash<int, int> PaginationHandler::pageIndex() const
{
    return opaque->pageIndexs;
}

void PaginationHandler::populatePageIndex(const int &sourceContainerSize, const int &resultPerPage)
{
    int loadedRecords = sourceContainerSize;
    int minumumPages {ONE};

    opaque->resultsPerPage = resultPerPage;
    if(loadedRecords <= opaque->resultsPerPage){
        opaque->pageIndexs.clear();
        opaque->pageIndexs[minumumPages] = loadedRecords;
    }else if((loadedRecords > ZERO && loadedRecords <= opaque->resultsPerPage)){
        opaque->pageIndexs.clear();
        opaque->pageIndexs[minumumPages] = loadedRecords;
    }
    else{
        opaque->pageIndexs.clear();
        while(loadedRecords > opaque->resultsPerPage){
            opaque->pageIndexs[minumumPages] = opaque->resultsPerPage;
            loadedRecords -= opaque->resultsPerPage;
            minumumPages++;
        }

        if(loadedRecords!=ZERO){
            opaque->pageIndexs[minumumPages]= loadedRecords;
        }
    }

}

QVector<int> PaginationHandler::pageNumber() const
{
    return opaque->pageNumbers;
}

void PaginationHandler::populatePageNumberContainer(const int &direction, const int &totalRecords)
{
    if(opaque->pageIndexs.isEmpty())
        return;
    int loopCtr{ZERO};
    int pageNumber{ONE};
    int maximumPages{ONE};
    if(opaque->pageNumbers.isEmpty()){
        emit prePageNumberChanged();
        while (loopCtr < opaque->pageIndexs.size()) {
            opaque->pageNumbers.append(pageNumber);
            ++pageNumber;
            ++loopCtr;
        }
        emit postPageNumberChanged();
    }else{
        emit prePageNumberChanged();
        CursorDirection dir = static_cast<CursorDirection>(direction);

        switch (dir) {
        case CursorDirection::MoveForward:
            pageNumber = opaque->pageNumbers.last();
            opaque->pageNumbers.clear();
            while (loopCtr<opaque->pageIndexs.size()) {
                opaque->pageNumbers.append(pageNumber+ONE);
                ++pageNumber;
                ++loopCtr;
            }
            break;
        case CursorDirection::MoveBackward:
            pageNumber = opaque->pageNumbers.first();
            opaque->pageNumbers.clear();
            while (loopCtr < opaque->pageIndexs.size()) {
                opaque->pageNumbers.append(pageNumber-ONE);
                --pageNumber;
                ++loopCtr;
            }
            std::reverse(opaque->pageNumbers.begin(),opaque->pageNumbers.end());
            break;
        case CursorDirection::MoveFirst:
            opaque->pageNumbers.clear();
            while (loopCtr < opaque->pageIndexs.size()) {
                opaque->pageNumbers.append(pageNumber);
                ++pageNumber;
                ++loopCtr;
            }
            break;
        case CursorDirection::MoveLast:
            opaque->pageNumbers.clear();
            maximumPages = int(ceil(double(totalRecords)/double(opaque->resultsPerPage)));
            while (loopCtr < opaque->pageIndexs.size()) {
                opaque->pageNumbers.append(maximumPages);
                --maximumPages;
                ++loopCtr;
            }
            std::reverse(opaque->pageNumbers.begin(),opaque->pageNumbers.end());
            break;
        }
        emit postPageNumberChanged();

    }

}

void PaginationHandler::setNavigationControl(const int &totalRecords, const int &sourceContainerSize, const int &direction)
{
    CursorDirection dir = static_cast<CursorDirection>(direction);

    switch (dir) {
    case CursorDirection::MoveForward:
        opaque->processedRecords += sourceContainerSize;
        break;
    case CursorDirection::MoveBackward:
        opaque->processedRecords -= sourceContainerSize;
        break;
    case CursorDirection::MoveFirst:
        opaque->processedRecords = totalRecords;
        break;
    case CursorDirection::MoveLast:
        opaque->processedRecords = sourceContainerSize;
        break;
    }
}

bool PaginationHandler::canMoveAhead() const
{
    return opaque->canMoveBack;
}

void PaginationHandler::setCanMoveAhead(bool val)
{
    opaque->canMoveAhead = val;
    emit canMoveAheadChanged();
}

bool PaginationHandler::canMoveBack() const
{
    return opaque->canMoveBack;
}

void PaginationHandler::setCanMoveBack(bool val)
{
    opaque->canMoveBack = val;
    emit canMoveBackChanged();
}
```

PaginationModel.h:

```
class IPaginationHandler;

class MetraPaginationModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(IPaginationHandler *handler READ getHandler WRITE setHandler NOTIFY handlerChanged)
public:
    enum {PageNumber = Qt::UserRole};
    explicit MetraPaginationModel(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override;
    QHash<int,QByteArray> roleNames()const override;

    IPaginationHandler *getHandler();
    void setHandler(IPaginationHandler *handlerInstance);

signals:
    void handlerChanged();
private:
    IPaginationHandler *handler;
};
```

PaginationModel.cpp

```
#include "paginationmodel.h"
#include "ipaginationhandler.h"
const int ZERO{0};

PaginationModel::PaginationModel(QObject *parent)
    : QAbstractListModel(parent),handler(nullptr)
{
}

int PaginationModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    if (parent.isValid() || !handler)
        return ZERO;
    return handler->pageNumber().size();
}

QVariant PaginationModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (!index.isValid() || !handler)
        return QVariant();
    switch (role) {
    case PageNumber:
        return QVariant(handler->pageNumber().at(index.row()));
    }
    return QVariant();
}

QHash<int, QByteArray> PaginationModel::roleNames() const
{
    QHash<int,QByteArray>roles;
    roles[PageNumber] = "page_number";
    return roles;
}

IPaginationHandler *PaginationModel::getHandler()
{
    return this->handler;
}

void MetraPaginationModel::setHandler(IPaginationHandler *handlerInstance)
{
    beginResetModel();
    if(handler)
        handler->disconnect(this);
    this->handler=handlerInstance;
    emit handlerChanged();

    if(handler){
        connect(handler,&IPaginationHandler::prePageNumberChanged,this,[=](){
            beginResetModel();
        });
        connect(handler,&IPaginationHandler::postPageNumberChanged,this,[=](){
            endResetModel();
        });
    }
    endResetModel();

}
```

Pagination.qml
This is just a snippet to get the idea how it would work on UI side

```
          ListView{
                id:paginationView
                implicitWidth: parent.width
                implicitHeight: parent.height * 0.15
                anchors.top: categoryList.bottom
                anchors.topMargin:Geometry.spacingVerticle * 3

                model: PaginationModel{
                    list:categoryHandler.pageList
                }
                delegate:Component{
                    PageIndicatorDelegate{
                        onPageIndexClicked:categoryHandler.getPageData(index)
                    }
                }
                spacing: Geometry.spacingHorizontal * 0.90
                orientation:ListView.Horizontal
                highlight: Component{IndicatorHighlightDelegate{}}
                highlightFollowsCurrentItem: true
                interactive:false
                header:Component{
                    ListViewNavigationControl{
                        onFirstIndicatorClicked: {
                            categoryHandler.moveBatch(Enums.MoveBackward)
                            paginationView.currentIndex = 0
                        }
                        onSecondIndicatorClicked:{
                            categoryHandler.moveBatch(Enums.MoveFirst)
                            paginationView.currentIndex = 0
                        }
                        secondIndicatorEnumeration: Qt.RightToLeft
                        firstControlVisible: categoryHandler.pageList.canMoveBack
                        secondControlVisible: categoryHandler.pageList.canMoveBack
                    }
                }
                footer:Component{
                    ListViewNavigationControl{
                        onFirstIndicatorClicked:{
                            categoryHandler.moveBatch(Enums.MoveForward)
                            console.log(MetraEnums.MoveForward)
                            paginationView.currentIndex = 0
                        }
                        onSecondIndicatorClicked: {
                            categoryHandler.moveBatch(Enums.MoveLast)
                            paginationView.currentIndex = 0
                        }
                        controlFirstIcon:  Icons.rightarrowThick
                        controlSecondIcon: Icons.rightarrowThick
                        firstControlVisible: categoryHandler.pageList.canMoveAhead
                        secondControlVisible:categoryHandler.pageList.canMoveAhead
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

This is Delegate Item

```
// This is a snippet so 
Item {
    id: number
    implicitWidth: Geometry.screenHeight * 0.03
    implicitHeight: Geometry.screenHeight * 0.03

    signal pageIndexClicked(var index)

    MouseArea{

        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked:{
            name.ListView.view.currentIndex = index
            pageIndexClicked(index+1)

        }
        hoverEnabled:name.ListView.view.currentIndex === index ? false:true
        onEntered:{pageNumber.color=ThemeLight.tertiarycolorLight}
        onExited: {pageNumber.color=ThemeLight.textcolor}
    }

    Label{
        id:pageNumber
        text:model.page_number ? model.page_number : index
        font.pixelSize:MetraGeometry.helpTextSize*1.2
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }


}
```

Comment: (I see a lot of erratic capital letters - do you use a spelling checker?) There are more code blocks than fit on my screen at once: could you please give an overview before the first one?

Comment: I know its bit too much code but its my first post and i am trying to get the hang of it I can share code on git hub if that helps in this regard.